# Connected / disconnected mouse - sidebar problem

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

Side bar appear only when mouse is connected. When mouse is disconnected, everything is okay.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvXpu.png)

I thought it was macOS problem, but its same on windows. I dont even know what should I google or how to name this problem.

Comment: Putting the actual code as a runnable snippet into your question should help us help you. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.